# Using HP QTP is there a way to test which button is the default?

Tags: qtp

Near as I can tell the only difference between a regular button and a default button is the border color. But, so far neither can I get to the buttons color nor does it have a property IsDefault.

The code I'm using to get the button is:

```
Set btnNo = frmMessageBox.SwfButton("Class Name:=SwfButton","swfname:=btnNo","text:=NO")
```

Seems to me testing if a button is the default button is a very reasonable test to perform. I was hoping someone would know of a better test that capturing a screen shot and measuring pixels.